# wsl: cannot move '/home'

Tags: directory, rename, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I cannot rename '/home' under wsl:

```
cd /

$ sudo mv /home home-old
mv: cannot move '/home' to 'home-old': Permission denied
```

Why I cannot rename '/home' under wsl, is there any workarounds?

Comment: Maybe you have some open files which prevent the renaming. Can you reboot your windows and then start a single wsl window and run your `mv` command ?

Comment: Found the reason, at least I believe so, WSL is installed with elevated privilege, while my wsl bash is started with normal privilege. There are just many things that cannot be done because of that, not just moving /home, any files/folders that need elevated privilege to access cannot be altered within wsl bash.

Comment: Maybe you can install another Linux distribution for test, run the same `mv` command and prove your theory.